# PostCSS nested variable

Tags: postcss

I have this code in my postcss file

```
.btn.color1>button{background:$graph_1;}
.btn.color2>button{background:$graph_2;}
.btn.color3>button{background:$graph_3;}
.btn.color4>button{background:$graph_4;}
.btn.color5>button{background:$graph_5;}
```

well, i thought this could be shorten by using for loops

```
@for $i from 1 to 5 {
    .btn.color$i>button{background:$graph_$i;}
}
```

but there was a problem. `$graph_$i` couldn't be resolved like `$graph_1`,
it just remained as `$graph_$i`.

is there any good solutions for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER 1**

I had to run postcss-advanced-variables twice. So, i remove precss from dependencies, and add it's inner dependencies directly on my project.

This is what I wrote in my webpack config file.

```
postcss: function(webpack) {
    return [
        ...
        require("postcss-advanced-variables"),
        require("postcss-advanced-variables"),
        ...
    ]
}
```

and in my PostCSS file,

```
@for $i from 1 to 5 {
    .btn.color$i > button{
        background: $(graph_$(i));
    }
}
```

**ANSWER 2**

I submit an issue at postcss-simple-vars, and Andrey Sitnik accepted it. Nested interpolation can used like [this](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars/commit/5b1cb42324c538c312550d67cd25f3e46050c1d7#diff-1dd241c4cd3fd1dd89c570cee98b79ddR137). But, it can't used with `@for` loop of postcss-advanced-variables